# Prolog error after returning true?

Tags: prolog

I am new to using Prolog so maybe im missing something obvious. I'm making a Tribonacci rule. Same as Fib, but `Trib[N] = trib[n-1]+trib[n-2]+trib[n-3]`, with 0, 1, 2 being 0, 0, 1 respectively.

What I have so far is :

```
trib(0,0).  
trib(1,0).  
trib(2,1).  
trib(N,T) :- A is N-1,   
    B is N-2, C is N-3,  
    trib(A,AT), trib(B,BT),  
    trib(C,CT), T is AT+BT+CT.
```

I get correct output to `trib(10,X)` and other cases, but when it returns, I get:

```
?- trib(4,X).  
X = 2   
Unknown action:  (h for help)  
Action?
```

I believe it is finding an error after returning X.

It seems to be waiting for commant to stop(enter), or look for more(space).

How to i make it stop after printing the answer?

Comment: It seems to be waiting for commant to stop(enter), or look for more(space). How to i make it stop after printing the answer?

Comment: Try putting `N > 2` in your final predicate to prevent it going negative and trying to recompute your base cases.

Comment: N > 2, helps it from running out of stack if i continue(space). But now it returns false. How do i get it to stop after finding one answer? i don't need it to go back to choice point.

Comment: Your query should succeed. Prolog only continues if you have it configured to do so. Your program doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to the question by defining (0, 1, 2) as `trib(0,0) :- !.`

Comment: This shouldn't make a difference when you have the `N > 2` in the general case predicate.

Answer (score -1):

@Enigmativity was almost right. You should use `!` in all of your predicates, at ends. Then prolog won't be able to try other solution. Like following:

```
trib(0,0) :- !.  
trib(1,0) :- !.  
trib(2,1) :- !.  
trib(N,T) :- A is N-1,   
    B is N-2, C is N-3,  
    trib(A,AT), trib(B,BT),  
    trib(C,CT), T is AT+BT+CT, !.
```

Other two solutions:

1. Use another predicate with !,
2. Use another predicate with once.

So in your usecase:

```
trib(0,0).  
trib(1,0).  
trib(2,1).  
trib(N,T) :- A is N-1,   
    B is N-2, C is N-3,  
    trib(A,AT), trib(B,BT),  
    trib(C,CT), T is AT+BT+CT,
tribonacci1(N,T) :- trib(N,T),!.
tribonacci2(N,T) :- once(trib(N,T)).
```

And than both of them (tribbonacci1 and tribonacci2) will execute once if you call them.

**Offtop:**

If you want it to be more efficient try to use helper function with 3 accumulators.